# Web scraping on android using python

Tags: android, python, web-scraping, scrapy

What can I do to scrape web pages using scrapy but on android?
If it can't be done then what are the other options that I can use(In Java maybe)? 
For example I wish to scrape [this](http://www.flipkart.com/globalite-stumble-walking-shoes/p/itmdzmejbtmfz9u8?pid=SHODPHXZZCGZG3BY&srno=b_2&ref=c1eb256c-618a-4e2b-ab5a-ac993b7a34f5) page for **Customers who viewed also viewed these** sections and extract the name, link, picture and price of the products listed there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `QPython`(http://qpython.com/) to execute python code on android. However,this tool may not have `scrapy` package, but you can use `urllib` and `urllib2`(`QPython` contain these two package).